# Writing a program in c++ to output string in reverse, getting no output as a result

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int i;
string userInput;
int index;

getline(cin, userInput);

index = userInput.length();

for(i = index; i <= 0; i--) {

cout << userInput.at(i);

}

return 0;
}
```

Program is generating absolutely 0 output. No errors or bugs, I just can't generate any output... Any ideas to why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the loop condition wrong

Try `i >= 0` (instead of `<=` )

In addition, you'll want to start the index at `index-1`

Working example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int i;
    string userInput;
    int index;

    getline(cin, userInput);

    index = userInput.length();

    for(i = index-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << userInput.at(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed the loop condition to that and now I'm getting this error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Why would it give me an error if it was just outputting i at the max length... isn't that equal to some character value? Thank you for the help.

Comment: In C, potentially, and it would be dangerous, but with std::string, no. Reference: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/ (The function automatically checks whether pos is the valid position of a character in the string (i.e., whether pos is less than the string length), throwing an out_of_range exception if it is not.)

Comment: Note that since the loop itself is already ensuring the `index` does not go out of bounds of the `string`, using `at()` to perform the same bounds checking is redundant. You can use `operator[]` instead: `for(i = index-1; i >= 0; i--) { cout << userInput[i]; }`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid indexing errors, use iterators:

```
for (auto it = std::crbegin(userInput); it != std::crend(userInput); ++it)
    std::cout << *it;
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Or range based for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> //for std::reverse

int main() {

  std::string userInput;

  std::getline(std::cin, userInput);

  //Print Reverse with for
  for(int i = userInput.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    std::cout << userInput.at(i);
  }

  std::cout<<std::endl;

  //Reverse userInput variable content and print
  std::reverse(userInput.begin(),userInput.end());
  std::cout<< userInput;

  return 0;
}
```